# Failed to create component 'BindingNavigator'

Tags: visual-studio

Here's what error I got while connecting the Access database to my Visual Studio.

[image]

I am confused about what to do next.

```
    Public Class main
    Const WM_NCHITTEST As Integer = &H84
    Const HTCLIENT As Integer = &H1
    Const HTCAPTION As Integer = &H2

    Private Sub main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DoubleBuffered = True
        Timer1.Start()
        Label1.Text = "Locker"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label1.Location = New Point(Label1.Location.X + 15, Label1.Location.Y)
        If (Label1.Location.X >= 330) Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            Timer2.Start()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        DoubleBuffered = True
        GroupBox1.Size = New Size(GroupBox1.Size.Width, GroupBox1.Size.Height + 10)
        If (GroupBox1.Size.Height >= 298) Then
            Timer2.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        Select Case m.Msg
            Case WM_NCHITTEST
                MyBase.WndProc(m)
                If m.Result = IntPtr.op_Explicit(HTCLIENT) Then m.Result = IntPtr.op_Explicit(HTCAPTION)
            Case Else
                MyBase.WndProc(m)
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The error says a file is not found... did you look for it?

Comment: My problem is solved just have to re-open the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing it from Resources from Properties(Alt+Enter). And Re-open it. I think whenever you delete any resource file which is been used by a form then the form designer code can not locate it so try this one also by removing the line of code from Form[Designer].vb (opening in Notepad++).